# key= , sorting in Python 2

Tags: python, sorting, key

I was looking over the how to guide for sorting in Python https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting and I was confused by the role that key= played in some of the example code. I obviously see how it changes when key= is used, but I'm confused why and I don't get why its the same result when key=str.lower and when key=str.upper.

I'd appreciate any help.

```
print sorted("This is a test string from Andrew".split()) 
#Output: ['Andrew', 'This', 'a', 'from', 'is', 'string', 'test']
print sorted("This is a test string from Andrew".split(), key=str.lower) 
#Output: ['a', 'Andrew', 'from', 'is', 'string', 'test', 'This']
print sorted("This is a test string from Andrew".split(), key=str.upper) 
#Output: ['a', 'Andrew', 'from', 'is', 'string', 'test', 'This']
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Wasn't sure what to expect. I thought the last result would be the same as the first one at first, but I think I get things now.

Comment: You get the same result because all elements in the list are converted for comparison by a choice of a given key so it doesn't matter if that is to lower or upper case.  The conversion applies only to comparisons, not to the actual values in the sorted list.

Comment: Were you expecting to actually see all uppercase or all lowercase strings in the sorted outputs?

Comment: No. I was just generally confused. Probably should've thought things through a little more, but I was frustrated. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, the function specified by the key only affects the elements during the sort.

So passing key=str.lower sorts ['andrew', 'this', 'a', 'from', 'is', 'string', 'test'], while passing key=str.upper converts sorts ['ANDREW', 'THIS', 'A', 'FROM', 'IS', 'STRING', 'TEST'].

Then it prints list elements with their original cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can see that uppercase letters come before lowercase letters in the first example. In the next two, you see that case doesn't enter into it, because every single character has been given the same case (for its sort order key). Therefore, either one ends up producing a "case-insensitive" sort order.

Imagine that your company has two departments: Research and Development. Now let's have a company event, and one of the games requires that we sort people by seniority. Now, the Research division came first, and Development was acquired in a hostile takeover a few years later, and since bonuses are determined by seniority, everyone in Research has an extra 100 years tacked onto their seniority value.

Two years later, the Development team has been folded into the Research team because people were demanding fairer bonuses. At the next company event, everyone is in Research, so everyone has that extra 100 years' seniority, so the order is determined by how long people have actually been with the company.

What would the result be if everyone had been folded into the Development team instead? Well, everyone would have a much smaller bonus, but they would still be lining up in that same order for company events.

Comment: Think I got it. So you're saying that the .lower and .upper only affect the sort command?